# Call C++/CLI function with Nullable datetime paramter using Nullable datetime return from C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have C# class (this class is hosted in a net core dll)

```
public class class1
{
  public DateTime? MyDateTime {get; set;}
}
```

Two functions in C++/CLI

```
public ref class class2
{
   public:
  class2(class1^ one)
  {
      _one = one;
   }
  function1(System::Nullable<System::DateTime> dateTime)
  {
  }
  function2()
  {
   function1(_one->MyDateTime);
  }
  private:
  class1 ^ _one;
}
```

My calling function is C# (this calling function is hosted in a .net 4.6.2 DLL)

```
class1 one = new class1();    
class2 two = new class2(one)
two.function2();
```

I got an error message saying the argument list doesn't match when calling function2. The compiler complains that the type for   "one.MyDateTime" is `System:Nullable` while the function1 requires `"System::Nullable <System::DateTime>"`.

Comment: Have you tried your example code? If I put void return on your C++/CLI functions (they don't return anything) and a semi-colon on your C# `two` instantiation then this compiles for me. (VS2017 - .NET 4.6.2) Please test that your examples are syntactically correct and exhibit the behavior you expect.

Comment: I think I know the reason of the problem now. However, I do not have a solution for it yet. Basically, I have three projects (C# net core access the database, C++/CLI accesses low level hardware C++ code, and the C# .net 462 legacy code running as a service). The problem occurred when C++/CLI calls C# net core DLL. Some however, the compiler translated System::Nullable<System::DateTime> into System::Nullable during the process. If I replace the C# net core DLL with .net462 DLL, the problem was gone. Now, I wonder what is the best way to call functions in net core DLL from C++/CLI.

Comment: What is the .NET core class and method that is returning the Nullable object that is giving you trouble?

Comment: ".NET core" is a different runtime than ".NET". The proper way to make a library compatible with both is to target ".NET standard".

Comment: I cannot compile the C++/CLI function2 calling function1. The compiler complains datetime parameter. I think the fundamental problem probably is that net core don' t have support for C++/CLI.

Comment: The C++/CLI and net462 are complex old codes that we have to use currently. The net core projects are recently created. Eventually, we will migrate our code to net core.